Pourquoi ne peut-on pas utiliser « requérir », comme 'require' en anglais, alors que 'require' découle de « requérir » ?
'require' procède de « requérir ». Mais pourquoi le français utilise-t-il beaucoup moins « requérir », que l'anglais n'utilise ‘require’ ?

The verbs "requérir" and "nécessiter" do mean "to need/require", but I feel like they apply to abstract concepts rather than an actual thing. You wouldn't use them to say "I need toothpaste" or even "I need to buy toothpaste", but for something like "this task requires all you attention". "Ce travail requiert toute ton attention". "Sa santé requiert des soins journaliers."

Exeter c. Canada (Procureur général), 2014 CAF 105 (CanLII) traduisit

Should you require further information please do not hesitate to get in touch with me.

par

Si vous avez besoin d’autres renseignements, n’hésitez pas à communiquer avec moi.

Pourquoi pas — Si vous requérez d’autres renseignements ... ?
High-Crest Enterprises Limited c. Canada, 2017 CAF 88 (CanLII) traduisit

If it’s option number one, I require an agreement in writing signed by counsel for the parties agreeing to have the appeal decided by a judge appointed by the Chief Justice based the trial record and the transcript.

Par

Si la première option est retenue, il me faut une entente écrite signée par les avocats des parties dans laquelle ils acceptent que l’appel soit tranché par un juge nommé par le juge en chef sur le fondement du dossier d’instruction et de la transcription.

Pourquoi pas — ... je requiers une entente écrite ... ?

Requérir has several meanings, so has require in English.  In the law field requérir has the meaning of "to demand" and is used quite a lot, *Je requiers une entente écrite..."  is entirely possible and correct in the context you describe. But I would understand Si vous requérez d'autres renseignements... as  "should you ask for further information...".  Comparing all the definitions of "require" in the OED and requérir in, for instance, the TLF would be a long but interesting search.

The words have evolved slightly differently since the 11th century (1st example given in the OED) and although they nowadays on the whole share quite a lot meanings it seems they belong to different language registers. I would say the English "require" is more  casual and the French requérir is more formal.  Adding to my 1st remark that the juridictionnaire has a specific entry for requérir & associated words.

Requirement does not have any exact French equivalent. In engineering, requirement(s) document usually translates to spécifications générales: document de {requêtes | réquisitions} would be completely lost on the readers. However, requête is the exact equivalent of request.

Words can be borrowed from one language to other ones and in the process and later, their meaning will often evolve, either by narrowing, widening or shifting away from their original one, and sometimes they die. Unborrowed word progress the same way, it's a natural law of language evolution.
Regarding requerir/require, it looks like that verb relaxed its 'commanding' meaning in English while it kept it in French.

Dictionnaire du Moyen Français (1330-1500):
REQUERIR, verbe   FEW X requirere
[T-L : requerre ; GD : requerre ; GDC : requerir ; DÉCT : requerre ; FEW X, 282b : requirere ; TLF XIV, 930a : requérir]
I. - [D'une pers.]
A. - "Chercher, rechercher qqn ou qqc. ; interroger qqn"
1. "Chercher, rechercher qqn ou qqc."
2. "Interroger qqn"
B. - "Solliciter qqn ou qqc."
1. Requerir qqn. "Solliciter qqn"
2. Requerir qqn / qqc. "Demander, réclamer qqn / qqc. (à qqn)"
C. - [Avec une idée d'hostilité] "Attaquer, reconquérir, défier"
1. "Attaquer qqn ou qqc."
2. "Défier qqn"
3. "Attaquer en justice, accuser"
II. - [D'une chose] Requerir qqc.
A. - "Exiger, nécessiter qqc."
B. - Requerir (un chemin). "Emprunter, suivre"

The evolution of the semantically close pair demander/demand seems to have followed symmetric paths. It is used a strong and insisting way in English while it is neutral in French.

+1 And quite true about demander and "demand"

The OED gives examples or "require" in the law field in the Middle-Ages. It seems to have lost its stronger meaning of  "to demand" around the 19th c.
